# C# VSTO Excel Addins: How can I access Ribbons Controls from the Addins ThisAddIn_Startup?

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-addins, customtaskpane

I'm designing an Excel Addins with Ribbons like this:

[image]

- The Ribbon Name is `Ribbon1`
- The Tab Name is `Tab1`
- The ToggleButton name is `tglShowNavigation`

What I need is:

> From the `ThisAddIn.cs`, in the `ThisAddIn_Startup` void, I would like to be able to **Affect/Change the ToggleButton tglShowNavigation's Label**.

I tried the following but cannot see any control from this:

[image]

Where and how could I access the Controls on my Ribbon from the `ThisAddIn_Startup` please?

NB: I don't want to call a global function from the Ribbon, but just want to be able to access them directly.

Thank you in advanced for you precious help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get access to the control by using

```
Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.tglShowNavigation
```

Make sure you've changed the modifier of the button to something you can reach, one example could be "Internal".

[image]

Comment: Wow, @UfguFugullu, it was the **Modifier** indeed that caused me not to access it. Now it's solved. You're just great, thank you very much.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that I could help