# Outlook VSTO AddIn: Update RibbonBar based on the text entered in the AppointmentItem.Body

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to update my custom Ribbon based on the text the user enters in AppointmentItem.Body.
I have 2 problems which I cannot resolve:
1.) I can't find an event that reliably is triggered when the user enters text in the Body of the AppointmentItem. I fear that there isn't any event that I can subscribe to. Correct?
AppPropertyChange does not work.

2.) I understand that the Ribbon has a link to the ThisAddIn instance. But there should not be a reference from ThisAddIn to the Ribbon in a correct architecture. Therefore even if I managed to find the right event to handle in ThisAddIn I wouldn't be able to call InvalidateUI on the Ribbon because I don't have a link to the Ribbon instance. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

**To your question number 1)**

I think there is no event listens to keydown or something else to the `AppointmentItem.Body`. Can't you better reverse the logic? So that after clicking on the ribbon button you check what's in the appointment?

**To your question number 2)**

The solution is to get the Ribbon about `Globals`. Make sure you get access to the ribbon and watch [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61057803/c-sharp-vsto-excel-addins-how-can-i-access-ribbons-controls-from-the-addins-thi)

```cs
public partial class ThisAddIn {

  Explorer activeExplorer;

  private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.activeExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
    this.activeExplorer.ViewSwitch += new ExplorerEvents_10_ViewSwitchEventHandler(this.ViewSwitch);
  }

  private void ViewSwitch() {
    bool isActive = false;

    try {
      Globals.Ribbons.CalendarRibbon.GroupCalendar.Visible = isActive;
      Globals.Ribbons.CalendarRibbon.ButtonCalendarSync.Visible = isActive;
    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
      // ... catch the exception
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Reg. Q1: No that is unfortunately not possible. The addin checks whether there are certain keywords contained in the body. And based on that the buttons should be (de-)activated.